# Improve PlaceHolder

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have implemented placeholder just like twitter and google does 
but i want to improve this code for some reason.
when someone inspect element i want to allow only input element to be get

Here is code

```
<style type="text/css">
    input.txtl{padding: 4px 4px;width: 100%;border: 0px}
    div.txtlo{width: 200px;position: relative;border: 1px solid #000099;}
    div.placer{position: absolute;z-index: 5;top: 0px;left: 0px;background: transparent;width: 100%;color: #cccccc;white-space: nowrap;padding: 2px;padding-left: 4px}
    div.hints{background: transparent;margin: 3px}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     function perform(val,hid){
        val=val.trim();
        if(val==""){
            $("#"+hid).show();
        }else{
            $("#"+hid).hide();
        }
    }
</script>
<div class="txtlo">
    <input type="text" class="txtl" id="us" onkeyup="perform(this.value,'plcus')" />
    <div class="placer" onclick="$('#us').focus()" id="plcus">Enter Password</div>
</div>
```

Now when i inspect this using default inspector of firefox i get this.

[image]

as you can see in this image blue border is shown this means my placeholder div is larger than input.....is there someway to make this both input and placeholder same on width and height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your css problem try this. Adjust to your needs.
 **Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/bCqQp/

```
.txtlo, .placer, .txtl {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.txtlo {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 0 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.placer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 0 1em;
}
.txtl {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey now used to this one as live this

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return submitenter(this,event)" id="" name="" onfocus="this.value = ''" onblur="if(this.value == '') this.value='Enter Password'" value="Enter Password">
```

### [**Live demo**](http://tinkerbin.com/t4owp0It)

**or this one**

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Password">
```

[**Live demo**](http://tinkerbin.com/gDY3b2Tf)

Comment: problem with this is that whenever user focus an element placeholder html remove but in my code when user key press and input's value changes then placeholder removed